# Trouble with a conditional join

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I'm trying to join depending on whether `table1.column1` is `null` or not `null`.

For, example I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`, and the query:

```
SELECT
    A.column2
FROM table1 A , table2 B
WHERE if A.column1 is not null then (A.column1=B.column1)
      else if A.column1 is  null then (A.column3 = B.column1);
```

Comment: It's advisable to use the normal `JOIN` syntax instead of putting all the tables on the `FROM` clause, which is deprecated.

Comment: This does not make sense. A.column1 is null then why would you want to join with B.column1.

Comment: There's a severe logic problem here. If A.column1 is NULL it is not possible for A.column1 = B.column1.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Sorry for not framing it properly...

Comment: What I'm trying to check if A.column1 is NOT null then (A.column1=B.column1) else if A.column1 is null then (A.column3=B.column1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    A.column2
FROM table1 A
JOIN table2 B ON
    B.column1 = A.column1 OR
    (A.column1 IS NULL AND B.column1 = A.column3)
```

Note that `B.column1 = A.column1` will never be true if either `B.column1` or `A.column1` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT A.column2
FROM table1 A 
    JOIN table2 B ON NVL(A.column1, A.column3) = b.Column1
```

If b.Column1 can also be null, and you want to compare two null columns, you can try this...

```
SELECT A.column2
FROM table1 A 
    JOIN table2 B ON NVL(b.Column1, 'X') = COALESCE(A.column1, A.column3, 'X')
```

Assuming b.Column1 can never have the value 'X'

Comment: it is giving me this error ORA-00904: "ISNULL": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Your tag says sql-server ? 
Change ISNULL to NVL

Comment: I tried using NVL.. But its not giving me the right result

Comment: Then you should clarify your question. This query does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Is b.Column1 also null?

Comment: Can you post sample data, with the expected result

Comment: Thanks!! Actually your initial answer helped me ....I had do some tweaking to my query